# When I change NEO-6m Baud Rate it looses it's accuracy

Tags: c++, arduino, gps

I have an actual legitimate NEO-6m that works fine on 9600 Baud. It is fairly accurate and it shows my house on google maps. However, when I go to u-center and change the Baud Rate to 115200, it looses it's accuracy by a couple streets. It goes from my house to about 30-ish miles away. I'm using this neo-6m with an Arduio Mega. I'm using the "Full Example" test code provided by the Tiny-GPS library, and I'm having no issues with that. Is there any way to change the Baud Rate and still keep it's accuracy?

Here is the code in case you want it:

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/*
   This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS++ (TinyGPSPlus) object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx).
*/
static const int RXPin = 10, TXPin = 11;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 115200;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);

  Serial.println(F("FullExample.ino"));
  Serial.println(F("An extensive example of many interesting TinyGPS++ features"));
  Serial.print(F("Testing TinyGPS++ library v. ")); Serial.println(TinyGPSPlus::libraryVersion());
  Serial.println(F("by Mikal Hart"));
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("Sats HDOP  Latitude   Longitude   Fix  Date       Time     Date Alt    Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum"));
  Serial.println(F("           (deg)      (deg)       Age                      Age  (m)    --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail"));
  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
}

void loop()
{
  static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

  printInt(gps.satellites.value(), gps.satellites.isValid(), 5);
  printFloat(gps.hdop.hdop(), gps.hdop.isValid(), 6, 1);
  printFloat(gps.location.lat(), gps.location.isValid(), 11, 6);
  printFloat(gps.location.lng(), gps.location.isValid(), 12, 6);
  printInt(gps.location.age(), gps.location.isValid(), 5);
  printDateTime(gps.date, gps.time);
  printFloat(gps.altitude.meters(), gps.altitude.isValid(), 7, 2);
  printFloat(gps.course.deg(), gps.course.isValid(), 7, 2);
  printFloat(gps.speed.kmph(), gps.speed.isValid(), 6, 2);
  printStr(gps.course.isValid() ? TinyGPSPlus::cardinal(gps.course.deg()) : "*** ", 6);

  unsigned long distanceKmToLondon =
    (unsigned long)TinyGPSPlus::distanceBetween(
      gps.location.lat(),
      gps.location.lng(),
      LONDON_LAT, 
      LONDON_LON) / 1000;
  printInt(distanceKmToLondon, gps.location.isValid(), 9);

  double courseToLondon =
    TinyGPSPlus::courseTo(
      gps.location.lat(),
      gps.location.lng(),
      LONDON_LAT, 
      LONDON_LON);

  printFloat(courseToLondon, gps.location.isValid(), 7, 2);

  const char *cardinalToLondon = TinyGPSPlus::cardinal(courseToLondon);

  printStr(gps.location.isValid() ? cardinalToLondon : "*** ", 6);

  printInt(gps.charsProcessed(), true, 6);
  printInt(gps.sentencesWithFix(), true, 10);
  printInt(gps.failedChecksum(), true, 9);
  Serial.println();
  
  smartDelay(1000);

  if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
    Serial.println(F("No GPS data received: check wiring"));
}

// This custom version of delay() ensures that the gps object
// is being "fed".
static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do 
  {
    while (ss.available())
      gps.encode(ss.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}

static void printFloat(float val, bool valid, int len, int prec)
{
  if (!valid)
  {
    while (len-- > 1)
      Serial.print('*');
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(val, prec);
    int vi = abs((int)val);
    int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
    flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
    for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
      Serial.print(' ');
  }
  smartDelay(0);
}

static void printInt(unsigned long val, bool valid, int len)
{
  char sz[32] = "*****************";
  if (valid)
    sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
  sz[len] = 0;
  for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
    sz[i] = ' ';
  if (len > 0) 
    sz[len-1] = ' ';
  Serial.print(sz);
  smartDelay(0);
}

static void printDateTime(TinyGPSDate &d, TinyGPSTime &t)
{
  if (!d.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print(F("********** "));
  }
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d ", d.month(), d.day(), d.year());
    Serial.print(sz);
  }
  
  if (!t.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print(F("******** "));
  }
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d:%02d:%02d ", t.hour(), t.minute(), t.second());
    Serial.print(sz);
  }

  printInt(d.age(), d.isValid(), 5);
  smartDelay(0);
}

static void printStr(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  smartDelay(0);
}
```

Comment: All components have tolerances.  You can attempt to calibrate the oscillator, get a new part in hopes of getting a better one, or be satisfied with a slower clock rate.  9600bps has twelve times the timing tolerance of the higher bit rate you tried.  In any event, this isn't a software question, it's a "understand tolerances and read the datasheet" question.  And "it's" and "its" are two different words for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you are using a software serial on pins 10 and 11? SS is based on bit-banging the UART signal, it works okay for low baud rates such as 9600, but 115200 is probably beyond its limits.

You could try connecting the GPS to one of 4 hardware serial ports, for example Serial1 (TX on 18 and RX on 19). This will require some modifications to the code:

- remove  `static const int RXPin = 10, TXPin = 11;` and `SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);`
- in `void setup()` change `ss.begin(GPSBaud)` to `Serial1.begin(GPSBaud)`
- in `smartDelay` function replace `ss.available()` with `Serial1.available()` and `ss.read()` with `Serial1.read()`

Comment: Hi, what is Serial1? Do you mean Serial?

Comment: @ComyarD No, I mean Serial1. Arduino Mega has 4 serial ports, have a look [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/)

Comment: But I don't think Serial1 is a command on Arudino? I know you can do Serial.available();

Comment: My bad I didn't know that existed. But how do I use all 4 of the serial ports? there are only Serial1- Serial3.Is Serial just general for all Serial ports or for Serial0?

Comment: Serial without any number, could be thought of as Serial0. On Arduino Mega it's connected to the USB port, while  Serial1, Serial2, Serial3 are free to use for other purposes, like GPS.